# Вопросы по классификатору текстов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Добрый день!
Реализую классификатор текстов, содержащих вопросы с этого сайта. На данный момент имеется вот такой код:

```
import requests
import nltk
import string

from collections import Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from pandas import DataFrame


from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import re
import os

# ----#
# количество классов для обучения
class_total = 0
# лист классов
class_list = []
# количество файлов в каждой папке для обучения
files_total = 3300
# лист файлов (с обучающей выборкой и не только)
files = []
files_class_num = []
# файлов загружено в словарь
file_num = 0
# классов загружено в словарь
class_num = 0

#print("Введите количество классов: ")
#class_total = int(input())
class_total = 2

classes_written = 0
# while classes_written < class_total:
#     print("Введите класс номер " + str(classes_written + 1) + ": ")
#     class_list.append(input())
#     classes_written += 1
class_list.append('cpp')
class_list.append('java')

# записываем тестовую выборку
while class_num < class_list.__len__():
    file_num = 1
    #пока не перебрали все обучающие файлы
    while file_num < files_total+1:
        # если такой файл существует
        # адрес типа : O:/lang/cpp/article_1.htm
        str1 = 'O:/lang/' + class_list[class_num] + '/article_' + str(file_num) + '.htm';
        if os.path.isfile('O:/lang/' + class_list[class_num] + '/article_' + str(file_num) + '.htm'):
            # октрыть файл
            current_file = open('O:/lang/' + class_list[class_num] + '/article_' + str(file_num) + '.htm', "r")
            # записать в переменную содержимое
            line = current_file.read()
            # переменная для удадения всех знаков препинания
            trantab = line.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))
            r = line
            text_without_punct = r.lower().translate(trantab)
            files.append(text_without_punct)
            files_class_num.append(class_num)
        file_num += 1
    class_num += 1

# записываем дополнительные тексты


count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
counts = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(files)

classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(counts, files_class_num)
print('обучение done')

joblib.dump(classifier, 'model of 3300.pkl')

prediction = classifier.predict(counts[4000])
if(prediction==0):
    print('это срр')
else:
    print('это java')
```

Обучающая выборка состоит из текстовых файлов по языкам cpp и java, по 3300 в каждой папке.

По данному коду есть несколько вопросов.

Первый, и самый главный - как реализовать обучение без необходимости держать огромный объём выборки в памяти разом, то есть как реализовать "добучение" по схеме: открыл файл - векторизовал - включил в существующую модель?

Второй вопрос - как выводить процент соответствия поданного на вход текста тому или иному классу (предположим, текст на 85% можно отнести к вопросам по java, и только на 15% - к cpp)?

Третий вопрос состоит в том, что у меня получалось брать контрольный пример для классификации только из самой обучающей выборки. В примерах в Сети чаще всего поступают так же. А как использовать случайный текст извне?

4й вопрос - какими методами процесс классификации можно сделать точнее? Буду благодарен, если вы подскажете ресурс, на котором можно почитать про ту или иную модель классификации на русском языке, желательно в сравнении / с примерами (текущая выбрана для проверки работоспособности).

Собственно, я буду рад любым замечаниям и советам по улучшению написанного.

Comment: Советую изучить [этот пример](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. То о чем Вы мечтаете называется "online learning" и поддерживается буквально парой алгоритмов.
   Весь остальной мир живет по принципу переодического обучения модели на обновленной тестовой выборке.

Подсластить пилюлю можно сохраняя обученную модель в файл. Как следствие для последующего применения модели не нужно каждый раз ее обучать.
См https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn

2. У некоторых классификаторов есть метод predict_proba (не у всех). Он позволяет вернуть оценку вероятности по каждому классу.
3. Плохой сценарий. Со всех сторон плохой. Это путь к переобучению.
   Правильный путь - дробить выборку на 3 части:
   а) На первой части (~70%) ведется обучение
   б) На второй части (~15%) ведется подбор оптимальных гиперпараметров (параметров классификатора)
   в) На третьей части вычисляется качество модели.
   См http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html
4. Совсем хороших материалов сходу не назову.
   Обычно все сводится к:
   а) Выбору хорошей модели (классические ML-модели против deep learning)
   б) Выбору фич (гуглите feature engineering)
   в) Сбору как можно большей обучающей выборке
   г) Грамотному выбору метрик и кроссвалидации
   Для начала рекомендую взять 3-5 самых популярных классификатора, обучить на каждом из них модели через кроссвалидацию и выбрать лучшую модель.